# NuxtJS: passing multiple parameters to a page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxtjs

In nuxt, how do you pass multiple parameters besides the ID.

This is my route.js file:

```
{
path: "/clip/:id?",
component: _548dcdc0,
name: "clip-id"
},
```

This is my nuxt link:

```
<div>
  <nuxt-link
  :to="{
  name: 'clip-id',
     params: {
       id: twItem.twId,
       slug: twItem.slug
     }
    }"
>
  {{ twItem.title }}</nuxt-link
>
</div>
```

And in mounted I have:

```
var self = this;
let id = this.$route.params.id;

self.slug = this.$route.params.slug;
console.log(self.slug);
```

I can get the id but slug is undefined here.

Comment: I maybe my answer has not to do about your question, actually I never create a route.js using nuxt, I end up using the folder structure to create my routes. So I always end up doing stuff like, :to="{ path: `/clip/${this.id}`, params: { slug: 'something' }}".

Comment: @drocha87 yes, route.js is generated by nuxt itself.